# How make the domain of a 2 variable function figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am writing some notes about 2-variable calculus and  I wondering how to reproduces this figure in TikZ.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: Same kind of diagram here  [How to make this diagram on Tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/555724/138900)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome! Several post of this type already exist, here is one more. One way to draw irregular shapes is to use `smooth cycle` through a set of coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Triangle,
    dot/.style={circle,fill=blue!70!black,inner sep=1.3pt}]
 \draw[orange,thick,fill=orange!50,xshift=1cm] plot[smooth cycle]
  coordinates {(10:0.5) (80:2) (140:2.8) (200:2.5) (250:2.7)   (290:2.2)
  (310:1.8)};
 \draw[thick,->] (-2,0) -- (3,0) node[below left]{$x$}; 
 \draw[thick,->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[below left]{$y$}; 
 \draw[thick,->] (4,-3) -- (4,3) node[below left]{$z$}
  node[pos=0.2,dot,label={right:$f(a,b)$}] (fab){}
  node[pos=0.8,dot,label={right:$f(x,y)$}] (fxy){}; 
 \draw[thick,blue!70!black,-{Stealth[bend]}] 
  (0.3,1.2) node[dot,label={right:$(x,y)$}] (xy){}
  to[bend left=50] (fxy);
 \draw[thick,blue!70!black,-{Stealth[bend]}] 
  (0.5,-1.2) node[dot,label={right:$(a,b)$}] (ab){}
  to[bend right=40] (fab);
 \draw (3.9,0) -- (4.1,0) node[right]{$0$}
  (0,0) node[below left] {$O$} (-135:1) node{$D$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I add my answer...also just for fun with...[Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor). If you like to draw :-) ...this is the original picture:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw    (289.5,251) -- (290.49,28) ;
\draw [shift={(290.5,25)}, rotate = 450.25] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 247; green, 212; blue, 116 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]  (182.5,87) .. controls (202.5,109) and (172.54,114.33) .. (166.5,126) .. controls (160.46,137.67) and (200.5,141) .. (197.5,163) .. controls (194.5,185) and (120.5,203) .. (87.5,182) .. controls (54.5,161) and (63,85.73) .. (87.5,71) .. controls (112,56.27) and (162.5,65) .. (182.5,87) -- cycle ;
\draw    (117.5,210.33) -- (117.5,38) ;
\draw [shift={(117.5,35)}, rotate = 450] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 60; green, 20; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 63; green, 13; blue, 210 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (124,80) .. controls (124,77.79) and (125.79,76) .. (128,76) .. controls (130.21,76) and (132,77.79) .. (132,80) .. controls (132,82.21) and (130.21,84) .. (128,84) .. controls (125.79,84) and (124,82.21) .. (124,80) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 60; green, 20; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 63; green, 13; blue, 210 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (286,71) .. controls (286,68.79) and (287.79,67) .. (290,67) .. controls (292.21,67) and (294,68.79) .. (294,71) .. controls (294,73.21) and (292.21,75) .. (290,75) .. controls (287.79,75) and (286,73.21) .. (286,71) -- cycle ;
\draw    (278.25,140) -- (301.75,140) ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 60; green, 20; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 63; green, 13; blue, 210 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (139,165) .. controls (139,162.79) and (140.79,161) .. (143,161) .. controls (145.21,161) and (147,162.79) .. (147,165) .. controls (147,167.21) and (145.21,169) .. (143,169) .. controls (140.79,169) and (139,167.21) .. (139,165) -- cycle ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 38; green, 7; blue, 211 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (128,80) .. controls (167.6,50.3) and (213.57,25.5) .. (283.86,69.64) ;
\draw [shift={(286,71)}, rotate = 212.76] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 38; green, 7; blue, 211 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 60; green, 20; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 63; green, 13; blue, 210 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (88,111) .. controls (88,108.79) and (89.79,107) .. (92,107) .. controls (94.21,107) and (96,108.79) .. (96,111) .. controls (96,113.21) and (94.21,115) .. (92,115) .. controls (89.79,115) and (88,113.21) .. (88,111) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 60; green, 20; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 63; green, 13; blue, 210 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (286,196) .. controls (286,193.79) and (287.79,192) .. (290,192) .. controls (292.21,192) and (294,193.79) .. (294,196) .. controls (294,198.21) and (292.21,200) .. (290,200) .. controls (287.79,200) and (286,198.21) .. (286,196) -- cycle ;
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 60; green, 20; blue, 237 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 63; green, 13; blue, 210 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (286,111) .. controls (286,108.79) and (287.79,107) .. (290,107) .. controls (292.21,107) and (294,108.79) .. (294,111) .. controls (294,113.21) and (292.21,115) .. (290,115) .. controls (287.79,115) and (286,113.21) .. (286,111) -- cycle ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 38; green, 7; blue, 211 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (88,111) .. controls (163.12,123.14) and (181.32,67.76) .. (284.44,110.35) ;
\draw [shift={(286,111)}, rotate = 202.74] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 38; green, 7; blue, 211 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
\draw    (83.5,139.33) -- (232.7,139.2) ;
\draw [shift={(235.7,139.2)}, rotate = 539.95] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 38; green, 7; blue, 211 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (143,165) .. controls (164.68,180.05) and (209.98,240.96) .. (283.76,197.35) ;
\draw [shift={(286,196)}, rotate = 508.4] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 38; green, 7; blue, 211 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;

% Text Node
\draw (111,147) node    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (91,165) node    {$D$};
% Text Node
\draw (150,88) node    {$(x,y)$};
% Text Node
\draw (310,147) node    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (322,69) node    {$f(x,y)$};
% Text Node
\draw (324,191) node    {$f(a,b)$};
% Text Node
\draw (164,160) node    {$(a,b)$};
% Text Node
\draw (106,36.33) node    {$y$};
% Text Node
\draw (306,28.33) node    {$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and with some metamorphosis, your figure appears almost similar to the original......
[image]

Excuse me **@Zarko** and **@Schrödinger's cat** ...but I like the drawing...,

Comment: How interesting. :)

Comment: @azetina So I'm emotional ahahahha...look I'm scarce and you all know it.

Comment: :) Good job at the diagram.

Comment: You guys are awsome

Comment: @Eduardo Here we are a great group ("Io sono il più scarso")! Don't forget it! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Compile here: http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/

```
unitsize(1cm);
path c= (2.8,3)..{(.75,0)}(3.5,2)..{(-1,0)}(3.5,-1.5)..(0,2)..cycle;
path xaxis=(-3,0)--(3,0), yaxis=(0,-3.5)--(0,4);
draw(Label("$x$",Relative(0.99)),xaxis,Arrow);
draw(Label("$y$",Relative(0.99),align=LeftSide),yaxis,Arrow);
filldraw(rotate(-50,(0,3))*c,orange+opacity(.5));
label(Label("$D$",Relative(.5)),rotate(-50,(0,3))*c);
draw(Label("$z$",Relative(0.99),align=LeftSide),shift((5,0))*yaxis,Arrow);
draw((0.3,1.5){dir(80)}..{dir(-40)}relpoint(shift((5,0))*yaxis,.8),Arrow);
draw((-0.8,0.8){dir(-20)}..(1,0.3)..{dir(-10)}relpoint(shift((5,0))*yaxis,.6),Arrow);
draw((0.6,-1.3){dir(-40)}..{dir(20)}relpoint(shift((5,0))*yaxis,.3),Arrow);
dot(Label("$(x,y)$",black),(0.3,1.5),dir(-5),blue);
dot(Label("$(a,b)$",black),(0.6,-1.3),dir(90),blue);
dot((-0.8,0.8),blue);
dot(Label("$f(x,y)$",black),relpoint(shift((5,0))*yaxis,.8),blue);
dot(Label("$f(a,b)$",black),relpoint(shift((5,0))*yaxis,.3),blue);
dot(relpoint(shift((5,0))*yaxis,.6),blue);
draw(Label("$0$",EndPoint),(4.9,0)--(5.1,0));
label("$0$",0,dir(-135));
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun.

To build the colorful set, I used the `curve to` operation with the `show curve controls` style from page 646 of the 3.1.5b manual (see below)

## Final result

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}      

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                                                         \usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
show curve controls/.style={
decoration={
show path construction,
curveto code={
\draw [blue, dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
\draw [blue, dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
}
},decorate
}
}
\tikzset{>=Stealth,
        every path/.style={very thick},
        every node/.style={font=\bf},
        point/.style={inner sep=1.3pt,fill,circle}
        }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}% left figure
% set
\draw[draw=red,fill=orange!80!green!20]%[postaction=show curve controls]
(-2.5,0) to[out=-90,in=180,in looseness=1,out looseness=1] 
(.5,-2.5) to [out=0,in=-90,in looseness=1,out looseness=.5] (2.8,-1)to[out=90,in=-90,in looseness=1,out looseness=1] 
(1.5,.5) to[out=90,in=-90,in looseness=.5,out looseness=.5] 
(1.9,1.5)to[out=90,in=0,in looseness=1,out looseness=1]
(.5,2.5)to[out=180,in=90,in looseness=1,out looseness=1] 
cycle;
% axis
\node[below left] at(0,0){$0$};
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(3.5,0)node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3)--(0,3)node[below left]{$y$};
% (x,y)
\node[point,label={right:$(x,y)$}](xy) at (.3,1){};
% (a,b)
\node[point,label={above:$(a,b)$}](ab) at (.5,-1.3){};
% point M
\node[point](M) at (-1,.5){};
\end{scope}


\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]% right figure
% axis
\draw[->] (0,-3.5)--(0,3.5)node[below left]{$z$};
% central point 0
\node [inner sep=1.5pt,fill,circle,label=right:$0$] at (0,0){};
% f(a,b)
\node [point,label={right:$f(a,b)$}] (fab) at (0,-1){};
% f(x,y)
\node [point,label={right:$f(x,y)$}] (fxy) at (0,2){};
% point M'
\node[point] (M') at (0,.8){};
\end{scope}

% arrows
\draw [->,violet] (xy)to[bend left](fxy);
\draw [->,violet] (ab) to[bend right](fab);
\draw [->,violet] (M) to[out=-20,in=180](M');
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## "show curve controls" style

[image: curve controls]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}      

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                                                         \usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
show curve controls/.style={
decoration={
show path construction,
curveto code={
\draw [blue,densely dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
\draw [blue,densely dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
}
},decorate
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=red,fill=orange!80!green!20][postaction=show curve controls]
(-2.5,0) to[out=-90,in=180,in looseness=1,out looseness=1] 
(.5,-2.5) to [out=0,in=-90,in looseness=1,out looseness=.5] (2.8,-1)to[out=90,in=-90,in looseness=1,out looseness=1] 
(1.5,.5) to[out=90,in=-90,in looseness=.5,out looseness=.5] 
(1.9,1.5)to[out=90,in=0,in looseness=1,out looseness=1]
(.5,2.5)to[out=180,in=90,in looseness=1,out looseness=1] 
cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Truly a good work....+1, but the `$D$` don't like? :-)

Comment: Indded. People will say that we should leave a bit of work for the person who asked the question

Comment: Ah, now I have undertsood.