# How to make this diagram on Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to make this diagram on Tikz?

[image]

Comment: Questions consisting in asking 'How to draw this thing?' are not reasonable questions to ask on this website. Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) of things you have tried so far and what specific issues you are specifically struggling with.

Comment: Same kind of diagram here  [How make the domain of a 2 variable function figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/533190/138900)

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun.

To build the colorful set, I used the `curve to` operation with the `show curve controls` style from page 646 of the 3.1.5b manual (see below)

## Final result

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}      

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                                                         \usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}

% style from manual 3.1.5b page 646
\tikzset{
show curve controls/.style={
decoration={
show path construction,
curveto code={
\draw [blue, dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
\draw [blue, dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
}
},decorate
}
}
\tikzset{>=Stealth,
        every path/.style={very thick},
        every node/.style={font=\bf},
        }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}% left figure
% set
\fill[orange!50!green!20]%[postaction=show curve controls]
(-1,-1) to[out=0,in=180,out looseness=1.5] 
(2,-2) to [out=0,in=0,in looseness=3,out looseness=2] (1,2)to[out=180,in=180,in looseness=1.5,out looseness=3] 
cycle;
% axis
\node[below left] at(0,0){$0$};
\draw[->] (-3,0)--(5,0)node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-3)--(0,3)node[below left]{$y$};
% circle 
\fill[orange!50!green!40,draw=orange!70] (1.5,1) circle [radius=6mm]node(ab)[inner sep=1.5pt,fill=black,circle]{};
% radius delta
\draw[very thick] (ab.center)--node[below]{$\delta$}+(150:6mm);
% (a,b) and arrow
\node [inner sep=1pt]at (2.6,.3){$(a,b)$} edge[->] (ab);
\end{scope}

% median arrow f
\draw[->] (6,0)--node[above]{$f$}(7,0);

\begin{scope}% right figure
% axis
\draw[->] (8,-3.5)--(8,3.5)node[below left]{$z$};
% central point
\node[circle,fill=blue!60,inner sep=1.5pt,label=right:$L$] (L)at (8,0){};
% brackets
\draw[Bracket-Bracket,draw=blue!60](8,-.8)node[right,xshift=2pt]{$L-\epsilon$}--+(0,1.6)node[right,xshift=2pt]{$L+\epsilon$};
% point 0
\node [inner sep=1.5pt,fill,circle,label=right:$0$] at (8,-3){};
\end{scope}

% blue arrow
\node[fill=blue!60,inner sep=1.5pt,circle,label={above right:$(x,y)$}](xy) at (1.6,1.3){};
\draw[->,blue!60,shorten >=2pt] (xy.center)to[out=-40,in=140] ([yshift=3pt]L.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

## "show curve controls" style

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}      

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}                                                         \usetikzlibrary {decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.misc}

\tikzset{
show curve controls/.style={
decoration={
show path construction,
curveto code={
\draw [blue, dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentfirst) -- (\tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
node [at end, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
\draw [blue, dashed]
(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) -- (\tikzinputsegmentlast)
node [at start, cross out, draw, solid, red, inner sep=2pt]{};
}
},decorate
}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% set
\fill[orange!50!green!20][postaction=show curve controls]
(-1,-1) to[out=0,in=180,out looseness=1.5] 
(2,-2) to [out=0,in=0,in looseness=3,out looseness=2] (1,2)to[out=180,in=180,in looseness=1.5,out looseness=3] 
cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wowwwwwwwwww...it is perfect...but missing the D of the domain ahahahah.

Comment: People will say that we should leave a bit of work for the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 5):

A drawing done with [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/editor)...this is a draft

[image]

it is not very ugly but a discrete compromise. This is the definitive output...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]


\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,428); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 428

%Shape: Polygon Curved [id:ds8220877533957465] 
\draw  [draw opacity=0][fill={rgb, 255:red, 233; green, 152; blue, 19 }  ,fill opacity=0.58 ] (167.5,111) .. controls (230.5,102) and (304.53,193.74) .. (274.78,248.75) .. controls (245.04,303.76) and (166.5,240) .. (102.5,259) .. controls (38.5,278) and (51.8,237.48) .. (50.5,199) .. controls (49.2,160.52) and (88.39,132.52) .. (106.46,125.56) .. controls (124.53,118.59) and (104.5,120) .. (167.5,111) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp8053898873122747] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 245; green, 166; blue, 35 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 238; green, 195; blue, 148 }  ,fill opacity=0.81 ][line width=2.25]  (154,178) .. controls (154,164.19) and (165.19,153) .. (179,153) .. controls (192.81,153) and (204,164.19) .. (204,178) .. controls (204,191.81) and (192.81,203) .. (179,203) .. controls (165.19,203) and (154,191.81) .. (154,178) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Axis 2D [id:dp23964265473819646] 
\draw  (114.5,228.4) -- (335.5,228.4)(136.6,79) -- (136.6,245) (328.5,223.4) -- (335.5,228.4) -- (328.5,233.4) (131.6,86) -- (136.6,79) -- (141.6,86)  ;
%Straight Lines [id:da3357919733676149] 
\draw    (171.5,160) -- (176.15,171.7) -- (179,178) ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4494288061260776] 
\draw    (214.5,209) -- (182.75,180.98) ;
\draw [shift={(180.5,179)}, rotate = 401.41999999999996] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp9447045465938679] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (175.5,178) .. controls (175.5,176.07) and (177.07,174.5) .. (179,174.5) .. controls (180.93,174.5) and (182.5,176.07) .. (182.5,178) .. controls (182.5,179.93) and (180.93,181.5) .. (179,181.5) .. controls (177.07,181.5) and (175.5,179.93) .. (175.5,178) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp9143649941039491] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (205.5,147) .. controls (205.5,145.07) and (207.07,143.5) .. (209,143.5) .. controls (210.93,143.5) and (212.5,145.07) .. (212.5,147) .. controls (212.5,148.93) and (210.93,150.5) .. (209,150.5) .. controls (207.07,150.5) and (205.5,148.93) .. (205.5,147) -- cycle ;
%Curve Lines [id:da6406848194974739] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ]   (209,147) .. controls (249,117) and (275.5,103) .. (307.5,146.5) .. controls (339.02,189.35) and (438.46,170.59) .. (471.06,223.53) ;
\draw [shift={(472.5,226)}, rotate = 241.03] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da945916143498928] 
\draw    (375,229) -- (393.5,229) -- (436.5,229) ;
\draw [shift={(439.5,229)}, rotate = 180] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da4346631711800999] 
\draw    (482.5,375) -- (482.5,82) ;
\draw [shift={(482.5,79)}, rotate = 450] [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.08]  [draw opacity=0] (8.93,-4.29) -- (0,0) -- (8.93,4.29) -- cycle    ;
%Straight Lines [id:da6125394256824868] 
\draw [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]    (482.5,200) -- (482.5,261) ;
\draw [shift={(482.5,261)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]      (6.71,-6.71) .. controls (3.01,-6.71) and (0,-3.7) .. (0,0) .. controls (0,3.7) and (3.01,6.71) .. (6.71,6.71) ;
\draw [shift={(482.5,200)}, rotate = 90] [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][line width=1.5]      (6.71,-6.71) .. controls (3.01,-6.71) and (0,-3.7) .. (0,0) .. controls (0,3.7) and (3.01,6.71) .. (6.71,6.71) ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp315010153312669] 
\draw  [color={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,draw opacity=1 ][fill={rgb, 255:red, 74; green, 144; blue, 226 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (479,230.5) .. controls (479,228.57) and (480.57,227) .. (482.5,227) .. controls (484.43,227) and (486,228.57) .. (486,230.5) .. controls (486,232.43) and (484.43,234) .. (482.5,234) .. controls (480.57,234) and (479,232.43) .. (479,230.5) -- cycle ;
%Shape: Circle [id:dp3707564917209931] 
\draw  [fill={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ,fill opacity=1 ] (479,333.5) .. controls (479,331.57) and (480.57,330) .. (482.5,330) .. controls (484.43,330) and (486,331.57) .. (486,333.5) .. controls (486,335.43) and (484.43,337) .. (482.5,337) .. controls (480.57,337) and (479,335.43) .. (479,333.5) -- cycle ;

% Text Node
\draw (115,73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$y$};
% Text Node
\draw (164,165.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\delta $};
% Text Node
\draw (315,230.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$x$};
% Text Node
\draw (118,209.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$O$};
% Text Node
\draw (216,200.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$(a,b)$};
% Text Node
\draw (166,123.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$(x,y)$};
% Text Node
\draw (396,203.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$f$};
% Text Node
\draw (486,333.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$O$};
% Text Node
\draw (500,187.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$L-\epsilon $};
% Text Node
\draw (501,253.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$L+\epsilon $};
% Text Node
\draw (501,221.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$L$};
% Text Node
\draw (490,76.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$z$};
% Text Node
\draw (84,167.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$D$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A picture for you!}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, that's nice, you should indicate how you use Mathcha and where it is.