# Commutative diagrams for map lifting

Tags: diagrams, commutative-diagrams

for the commutative diagrams I use tikz-cd but now I saw this commutative diagram on Kosniowski and I have no idea. Can someone send me a code? Thanks before.

[image: diagram]

[diagram on google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yrUeeuGLuyduL6TirEifseBsUevB3uF4/view)

Comment: Hi and welcome. The only difficult thing is to draw diagrams of any shape imitating a freehand drawing. If you use geometric shapes like ellipses or even clouds, it's much easier with TikZ. What's your problem here?

Comment: I don't know how to drow the figures...

Comment: If you have difficulty drawing these figures with TikZ, it's normal, it's difficult. I advise you to draw them online on the web with a specialized software such as  [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io), which [@Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/555753/138900) here very often praises the possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thank you very much for the my nomination of the very nice user `@AndréC`. In the meantime I have read your question:

"*for the commutative diagrams I use `tikz-cd`*". Ok, it is a good start point. If you read the manual of [`tikz-cd`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf) (to the pag. 13), you can see that there is the use of `\begin{tikzpicture}`, that is very important to give you almost an answer.

`tikz-cd`, hence, use `TikZ` like great support, and it is important to know of this last package: I add, very well of the knowledge of this package. To build this MWE I have dedicated, for example, near one hour...(I remember I'm a snail)...

**Starting point: approximate drawing**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& & D \arrow[d] \\
A \arrow[r] \arrow[rru, bend left] &  \begin{tikzpicture}\node[circle,draw] at (0,0) {$\wideparen{\varphi(0)=y_0,\,\varphi(1)=y_1}$};
\end{tikzpicture} \arrow[r,"f"] & \begin{tikzpicture}\node[ellipse,draw,label={[xshift=3.3cm, yshift=-1.2cm]$X$}] at (1,0) {$f_{\varphi}(0)=x_0,\, f_{\varphi}(1)=f_{y}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

So inside each element of the matrix you can add a contour (for simplicity I have built a circumference and an ellipse) accompanied by a label but always using `TikZ`, because `tikz-cd` has no predefined shapes, like clouds, stars inside of which you could put a formula. The solution for me is unique, you have to learn at least the basics of TikZ, because everyone acquires the skills by reading and studying the packages. None of us have the magic stick.

[image]

I had a trial run with **Mathcha** that is absolutely not elegant. The drawing is very approximate. You could to have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
\draw [line width=1.5]    (43,287.33) -- (144.5,287.33) ;
\draw    (169.5,287.33) -- (231,287.33) ;
\draw [shift={(233,287.33)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
\draw    (115,275.33) .. controls (137.28,157.52) and (283.53,120.08) .. (333.03,118.37) ;
\draw [shift={(334.5,118.33)}, rotate = 538.81] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (274,257.33) .. controls (284,252.33) and (373.17,228.33) .. (403.17,247.33) .. controls (433.17,266.33) and (412,321.33) .. (393.17,322.33) .. controls (374.33,323.33) and (340.33,322.33) .. (306.17,322.33) .. controls (272,322.33) and (243.4,304.08) .. (245.17,290.33) .. controls (246.94,276.58) and (250.76,276.46) .. (256.5,270.55) .. controls (262.23,264.65) and (269,259.83) .. (274,257.33) -- cycle ;
\draw    (285,277.33) .. controls (323.17,264.33) and (315.17,280.33) .. (332.17,274.33) .. controls (349.17,268.33) and (346.17,283.33) .. (372.17,274.33) ;
\draw    (426.5,288.33) -- (473,288.33) ;
\draw [shift={(475,288.33)}, rotate = 180] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (517,254.33) .. controls (525.5,256.2) and (607.5,225.2) .. (637.5,244.2) .. controls (667.5,263.2) and (660.5,317.2) .. (636.17,319.33) .. controls (611.83,321.47) and (583.33,319.33) .. (549.17,319.33) .. controls (515,319.33) and (480.83,323.07) .. (480.5,289.2) .. controls (480.17,255.33) and (486.76,263.11) .. (492.5,257.2) .. controls (498.24,251.29) and (508.5,252.47) .. (517,254.33) -- cycle ;
\draw    (517.5,284.2) .. controls (557.5,254.2) and (586.5,254.2) .. (625,273.2) ;
\draw  [line width=1.5]  (412.5,51.2) .. controls (421,53.07) and (486.5,32.2) .. (562.5,58.2) .. controls (638.5,84.2) and (581.5,145.2) .. (567.5,157.2) .. controls (553.5,169.2) and (433.5,151.2) .. (399.5,161.2) .. controls (365.5,171.2) and (344.33,149.2) .. (344,115.33) .. controls (343.67,81.47) and (346.76,90.11) .. (352.5,84.2) .. controls (358.24,78.29) and (404,49.33) .. (412.5,51.2) -- cycle ;
\draw    (382.5,132.2) .. controls (397.5,112.2) and (418.31,94.7) .. (445.5,93.2) .. controls (472.69,91.7) and (516.25,100.7) .. (535.5,110.2) ;
\draw    (522.5,171.2) -- (522.98,235.33) ;
\draw [shift={(523,237.33)}, rotate = 269.57] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
% Text Node
\draw (45,290.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$0$};
% Text Node
\draw (135.5,290.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$1$};
% Text Node
\draw (91,266.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$I$};
% Text Node
\draw (198,265.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\varphi $};
% Text Node
\draw (250.17,280.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\varphi ( 0) =y_{0}$};
% Text Node
\draw (344.17,279.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\varphi ( 1) =y_{1}$};
% Text Node
\draw (443,266.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$f$};
% Text Node
\draw (487.17,288.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$f_{\varphi }( 0) =0$};
% Text Node
\draw (562.17,271.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$f_{\varphi}(1) =f(y)$};
% Text Node
\draw (401.17,325.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$Y$};
% Text Node
\draw (639.17,322.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$X$};
% Text Node
\draw (365.17,130) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\tilde{f}_{\varphi}( 0) =\tilde{x}_{0}$};
% Text Node
\draw (534.17,96.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\tilde{f}_{\varphi }( 1)$};
% Text Node
\draw (530,192.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$P$};
% Text Node
\draw (592,133.73) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\tilde{X}$};
% Text Node
\draw (159,141.6) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\widetilde{f_{\varphi}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{Diagram on Kosniowski}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you created a spline that wrapped a formula you would have to find the right coordinates and this is a big problem because **Mathcha** uses a lot of code and you would lose a lot of time. So the advice I give you so sincerely to approach `TikZ` very slowly...